# Highlight particular div text on click

Tags: c#, jquery, css

I have following HTML.

```
<div id = "aa">
        <table width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <!-- ngRepeat: msg in globalChat -->
                <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="msg in globalChat" ng-1375781897068="8">
                    <td class="ng-binding" ng-1375781897068="9">
                        A
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="msg in globalChat" ng-1375781897068="10">
                    <td class="ng-binding" ng-1375781897068="11">
                        B
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="msg in globalChat" ng-1375781897068="12">
                    <td class="ng-binding" ng-1375781897068="13">
                        C
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="msg in globalChat" ng-1375781897068="14">
                    <td class="ng-binding" ng-1375781897068="15">
                        D
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="msg in globalChat" ng-1375781897068="16">
                    <td class="ng-binding" ng-1375781897068="17">
                        E
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="msg in globalChat" ng-1375781897068="18">
                    <td class="ng-binding" ng-1375781897068="19">
                        F
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="msg in globalChat" ng-1375781897068="20">
                    <td class="ng-binding" ng-1375781897068="21">
                        G
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="msg in globalChat" ng-1375781897068="22">
                    <td class="ng-binding" ng-1375781897068="23">
                        H
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="msg in globalChat" ng-1375781897068="24">
                    <td class="ng-binding" ng-1375781897068="25">
                        I
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="msg in globalChat" ng-1375781897068="26">
                    <td class="ng-binding" ng-1375781897068="27">
                        J
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="ms`enter code here`g in globalChat" ng-1375781897068="28">
                    <td class="ng-binding" ng-1375781897068="29">
                        K
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**I have used AngularJS to render values**

I simply want that if I click on any text in div then only that particular text should be highlighted in div. And by clicking on other text in div previously selected text should be deselected and new text should be selected. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/bT8vs/

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div p').click(function(){
       $('div p').css("background-color", "transparent");
       $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much the same answer as imconnell, but applied to the given layout: http://jsfiddle.net/rpqvX/7/

```
$(function() {
    $("td.ng-binding").click(function() {
        $("td.ng-binding").removeClass("highlight");
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
    });
})
```

Comment: Actually a better answer since it adds a class rather than edits CSS directly.

Comment: i am binding data with following code and use your answer but it does not work...  <div id="divUsers" ng-controller="ChatCtrl" >
            <table width="100%" border = "0">
                <tr ng-repeat="msg in globalChat">
                    <td class = "ng-binding">
                        {{msg.name}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

Comment: Could you please create a new jsFiddle and paste the link here?

Comment: The td cells you want to highlight must have the class "ng-binding", or else change the jquery selector.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, have a look at the following jQuery plugin:

[highlight: JavaScript text higlighting jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)